# Calculate centre of area(or weighted centre based on area) of polygon in python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis, shapely

There are many methods to calculate the centroid of a polygon in PostGIS and even we can find inner centroid(representative point) too.
But is there any method to calculate weighted centroid based on the area of the polygon.

For e.g. I have a multi-polygon consist of two polygons (let's say `P1` and `P2` with area `A1` and `A2` respectively and `A1` >> `A2`).
But geometry wise their actual centroid lies outside both polygons but as `A1` >> `A2`, so I need this centroid should be shifted closer to `P1`.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, could you provide some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: @JimJones +1 to your comment for the nice phrasing!

Comment: @JimJones I have sample data but don't have their results, so I have updated the description to explain it by an example. hope this help.

Comment: @MohitRajpoot: Add examples that people can really use. If you mention P1 and P2, also share their WKT. It sounds like too much work, but it will **significantly** improve your chances to get an answer. Long story short: the easier to reproduce the better.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of [`ST_Centroid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html):

> ... For [MULTI]POLYGONs, "weight" is thought in terms of area ..

That being said, your centroid will be placed closest to the larger area.

Example:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((8.55 48.23,12.07 48.23,12.07 47.41,8.55 47.41,8.55 48.23)),
             ((13.34 53.47,22.62 53.47,22.62 51.68,13.34 51.68,13.34 53.47)))
```

[image]

Computing the centroid using `ST_Centroid` will give you the following point ..

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(
    ST_Centroid('MULTIPOLYGON (((8.55 48.23,12.07 48.23,12.07 47.41,8.55 47.41,8.55 48.23)),
              ((13.34 53.47,22.62 53.47,22.62 51.68,13.34 51.68,13.34 53.47)))'));

                st_astext                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(16.8445429181027 51.8710758247169)
(1 Zeile)
```

.. which is weighted by area and therefore closer to the larger polygon of your multipolygon:

[image]